# Android: include a xml into an other xml

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

How to include a xml data into an other xml data?

I have a header xml-file for my application which I want to use in my special other content xmls. Is there a ways to include the header into my content?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

use include tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
  <!-- Header -->
  <include
    android:id="@+id/container_header_lyt"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above=...
    android:layout_toLeftOf=...
    layout="@layout/header_logo_lyt" //Name of the xml layout file you want to include
    />     

...

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I haven't tried with a RelativeLayout but it should. Probably you will have to set within the include tag the properties that sets where it has to be placed: android:layout_above, android:layout_toLeftOf, etc...

Comment: it dont work for me with realtive layout may my error is somewhere else ill post my code

Comment: I have edited the answer to adapt it to the RelativeLayout case

Comment: match_parent isnt allowed for RelativeLayout

Comment: Use fill_parent instead. I pasted my code and I am working with honeycomb, thats why I was using match_parent. But it should work with fill_parent. Play a bit with your code.

Comment: mhh it work now no exception anymore but it only display my header not my content...

Comment: @Tobi play a bit with your layouts. You already know how to include a xml into an other xml. If only your header is being showed is because probably you are not setting well your layout attributes. This is a bit tricky at the beggining but is a matter of time. Check the attributes of the layout you are including, the attributes of the container layout, and play with relativelayout attributes.. etc.

Answer (score 12):

You have to declare your "body" xml layout with a < merge > tag to use < include > tag on your principal layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge>
    <ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/image" / >

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:background="#AA000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:text="Some Text" / >
</merge>
```

This is the content of your < include > tag

Answer (score 6):

You should use < include > tag: [Re-using Layouts with](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)