# Can I reference a gradient resource in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, gradient

I would like to be able to define a gradient drawable and then reference this gradient in other shape drawables. Is something along these lines possible, or do I have to specifiy the gradient in every shape resource over again?

in file my_gradient.xml

```
<gradient
    android:angle="180"
    android:endColor="@color/Gradient2Light"
    android:startColor="@color/Gradient2Dark" >
</gradient>
```

and then just have

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<gradient id="@drawable/my_gradient" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#2f6699" />

<corners android:radius="3dp" />
```

Is something like this possible and if yes, then how?

Comment: I am not aware that this is possible. I suppose you could see if `<include>` tags work, like they do in layout resources, but AFAIK `<include>` is a layout-only thing. Beyond that, stick `180` in an integer resource, and at least your values will be centrally defined, even if the `<gradient>` element itself will not.

Comment: You could try the [include tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306791/android-include-a-xml-into-an-other-xml) like described here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306791/android-include-a-xml-into-an-other-xml>