# android include a xml into another xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, include

I'm writing a widget with several differet sizes.
they all have the same intent filters, so I thought
of putting them into an `intents.xml` and include that file everytime I need it.

in android there is a

```
<include android:layout="bla.xml"/>
```

but only for layouts.
So how can I inlude any xml file i want to include?

---

EDIT:
maybe it wasn't clear enough, so here again:
I have asked for ***`non layout files`*** -> i need ***`intent-filters`*** included!

Comment: http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/ and check this http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html. use `<include layout="@layout/bla"/>`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306791/android-include-a-xml-into-an-other-xml

Comment: i asked for ***`non layout files`***

Comment: **The <include /> does exactly what its name suggests; it includes another XML layout**.

Comment: read my question and you'll see, i describe including **`intent-filters`** ***NOT*** `layouts`

Comment: You keep on saying that, but intent filters only exist in the manifest.  Even if you could do this, putting an intent filter into a layout makes no sense semantically.

Comment: i dont want to put intent filter into a layout.
i'm talking about androidmanifest.xml. i have more than one widget, and they all take the same intent-filters. so insted of writing the same intent-filters 20 times i wantet to include them from a additional file.